# Use password instead of public key for git

Tags: git

I have ssh forwarding set up so that I can access a private Github repo from my server (B), so long as I'm connecting from the machine with the correct keys (A). This looks like:

```
A -ssh-> B -git/ssh-> Github
```

What should I do if I want to access the repo from server B but connected through a different machine (C)?

```
C -ssh-> B -git/ssh-> Permission denied (publickey)
```

I don't own C, so I'd like to avoid adding public keys from C to the whitelist for my repo. If possible, I'd like to tell git to authenticate with my username and password for this session only.

**EDIT**: I tried routing through A (`C -> A -> B -> Github`), but this also fails with a public key mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have should set up something like gitlite. I believe that is the bare bones version where it sets up "users". Normally I set up a full stack like gitorious/gitbucket/gitlab which accomplishes the same thing.